# Get Post meta to display on invoice in WordPress

Tags: woocommerce, invoice

I'm using a plugin called woo-get to add a product attribute called 'prod_hsn_id' which add a filed called HSN code at product edit page,
I'm also using a pdf invoice plugin called woocommerce pdf invoice to generate pdf invoice.
Now I want to display the HSN code on the invoice.

I am having a very hard time to get it to work, I tried searching online and contacting the plugin author, and he said that it can be retrieved using the WordPress get post meta.

But

This the function the plugin use to create the custom field.

```
public function fn_add_product_custom_meta_box() {
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( 
        array( 
            'id'            => 'hsn_prod_id', 
            'label'         => __('HSN Code', 'woocommerce' ), 
            'description'   => __( 'HSN Code is mandatory for GST.', 'woocommerce' ),
            'custom_attributes' => array( 'required' => 'required' ),
            'value'         => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'hsn_prod_id', true )
            )
        );
}
```

In the Invoice Template file I'm trying to display the HSN Code using

```
<?php $meta = get_post_meta( $post_id , 'hsn_prod_id', true ); ?>
<?php $meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'hsn_prod_id', true ); ?>
```

Sources :

Support 
1. https://wordpress.org/support/topic/print-hsn-in-invoice/

2. https://wordpress.org/support/topic/which-pdf-plugin-will-display-the-hsn-field-and-gst-number/

Answer (score 0):

Product details will be under line_items of order. Can you share your invoice template code where you are trying to access product id?

You will have order object, using that object you can retrieve all products related to that order. You need to execute on foreach loop (that should be there already).

You can see `$product` at line 77 of original template file of plugin. You can get id using `$product->get_id()`.

Comment: I'm editing the invoice php file to add hsn code in the product detail table, So when generating the invoice pdf.

unfortunately using     $product->get_id() throws an error.

Comment: Do `print_r($product); exit;` once and check that array values first and then try to access its properties. If possible, show me that.